# How to DM the person who is executing the command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that DM's a person with text and some arguments from it while sending a message with those same arguments to a channel.

Right now I am trying to figure out the DM part. All the threads that may have helped me were from 2 years from the old discord.py.

Here is my attempt at DMing the person who runs the command:

```
@bot.command
async def report(ctx):
    user = await ctx.message.author.id
    await DMChannel.send(user, "lol")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

I essentially just two string arguments, `!report <name> <reason>`. I will use them in the DM and message to a channel. But right now, all I need is to find a way to DM a person something.

I got the DMchannel idea from this video, but it shows you how to send it to a specified person, not the context (I think). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyctSEjJ8r0

Comment: have you tried `await user.send("message")`?

Comment: "All the threads that may have helped me were from 2 years from the old discord.py." Are you using the rewrite? If so, there is a `discord.py-rewrite` tag you can use for the question.

Answer (score 1):

So it was actually really simple.

To have an await statement send a DM to the invocator of the command, I had to do this:

```
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx, user, reason):
    await ctx.author.send("Haha :D")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make a DM command too, and this was as close as i could get.

```
@bot.command
async def dm(ctx,member:discord.Member,*,content):
    user = await member.create_dm()
    await user.send(content)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Here is the link to [`create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_dm#discord.User.create_dm) that I took as help